# Issue while publishing Web in VS2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, visual-studio-2012, unity-container

Am working on MVC project with Different layers(Main project MVC Web other projects are Class libraries where Bin points to MVC web Bin Folder) with Dependency Injection using Unity.

While running in my local machine everything looks fine. If i publish my Web and browse the application am getting

The given assembly name or codebase was invalid.

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.LoadConfiguration();        //Error line
```

I took some time to see the issue and found that in my Published Bin Folder my Business and Data Access DLL's are missing ?

Is this because of Unity ? because my interface refers to Business layer through unity?

Am i missing something or how i publish without any issues ?

PS :if i copy the DLL and put in virtual Directory folder everything looks fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In a web project, or any final project that employs dependency injection (could be WPF or Silverlignt application, even classic ASP.NET), **all binaries** that are used should be made **available**.

Imagine you have `Lib1.dll` and `Lib1.Impl.dll`, respectively an API library and a concrete implementation of the API. Now, in the web project you *rely* on dependency injection to provide you with concrete implementation of the interfaces from the `Lib1.dll`. You may *never happen to use a class from `Lib1.Impl.dll` directly* in that application. Still, **the DI framework needs to access** the `Lib1.Impl.dll` in order to instantiate the dependencies.

Depending on the DI framework and the supported capabilities of loading dependencies, you should provide them accordingly. It seems straightforward to have them all in the bin folder, or referenced directly by the final project - that is probably the reason your project works when you provide the implementation dll-s in the bin folder. Since, however, this goes against the considerations of decoupling, you may have to look at alternative approaches to dynamically load dll-s - by physical location for instance. I am sure Unity supports mechanisms for this, since Modularity in Enterprise Library allows for bootstrapping modules from a filesystem location.

I must say, though, while I mentioned decoupling and keeping the references separate, this is **not an issue** if you have them all referenced in the final tier of the project hierarchy (the web application), **as long as you do not have code that causes coupling** in that application.